# No Adapters in Network connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers

After trying to fix this for hours I finally have to ask for help.

After having tampered with bridging between my WiFi and LAN (like I did countless times before) I was unable to remove the bridge between the two adapters and, stupid as I was, uninstalled both via Device manager (as advised by another forum).

Now, my problem is that the network connection is empty: no adapters.
Tried the fix that was given with deleting the config in the registry:

> LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Network

or rather I would have, but I don't even have the config.

Tried reinstalling drivers for both wireless and wired, both are timing out with the excuse that I do indeed have compatible software but there was an unknown error.

Both show up in Device Manager and are totally fine (at least they say)
No sign of them in `ipconfig /all`.

```
Running Win10 64, no VPN installed.
Motherboard is an Asus P8Z77-V.
Lan Adapter is titled as: Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection.
WiFi as: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485-Wireless Adapter.
And there is like 8 WANT mini ports.
```

How do I get back online?